# Quick Look pops up when switching desktops

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, quicklook

When switching between desktops, sometimes Quick Look pops up all by himself. Even when switching for a desktop containing a terminal, Quick Look pops up for a path that might be in the terminal's output. It is very annoying.

Someone knows how to solve this?

I'm currently using Catalina v10.15.5 on a 2016 MacBook Pro 13'' Touch Bar.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you share a screenshot?

Comment: @howdytom, here is the screenshot you've asked. Not sure if it helps much...

Comment: Did you close any Quick Look windows in Finder before switching desktops? It looks the keyboard shortcut cmd Y is still being pressed.

Comment: @howdytom, yes. Now Quick Look windows were open and no keyboard shortcut was being pressed.